# Experience Manager - Tridion 2011

Tags: 2011, experience-manager

I am using Tridion 2009 SP1 for a client, we have jsp pages and vb script. Our client wants to switch to Tridion 2011 and have told to investigate Experience Manager. I tried searching on sdllivecontent but could find anything with this word. Can anyone direct me what actually is Experience Manager so that i can get back to client and estimate the efforts required when i migrate to Tridion 2011

Answer (score 13):

Experience Manager is the product formerly known as the SDL Tridion User Interface (UI) update, formerly known as SiteEdit.

You can find information on Tridon World for UI Update 
(https://www.sdltridionworld.com/downloads/documentation/UIU4SDLT2011SP1/index.aspx) if you have access, as well on SDL Live Content
(http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/UIU4SDLT2011SP1/concept_EDC411EF58BD4700A8B6BD996AB102F3).

I suppose the reasoning behind the re-renaming of the product is due to its becoming more integrated into the main Content Manager Explorer interface.

Answer (score 4):

The name *Experience Manager* (we usually abbreviate it here as XPM) is really only used in the official documentation on the latest release, version 2013. Before that (version 2011) the documentation refers to it as *user interface update for SDL Tridion 2011 SP1* which is basically the same as *SiteEdit* was for version 2009 and before (be it that XPM comes with added features).

You can find it in the online documentation for SDL Tridion 2013 under [Content Manager clients](http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL_Tridion_2013/concept_1090E3E576634CB2BE890CCDE15D2299) ([requires login](http://docportal.sdl.com/sdltridion))

For the details of the implementation on SDL Tridion 2011, you can use [Welcome to the user interface update for SDL Tridion 2011 SP1 documentation](http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/UIU4SDLT2011SP1/concept_EDC411EF58BD4700A8B6BD996AB102F3) ([requires login](http://docportal.sdl.com/sdltridion))

Also Ryan Durkin has written a nice article with a very complete overview of it all: http://blog.building-blocks.com/sdl-tridion-user-interface-2012-overview

Answer (score 4):

See the naming history in the other answers, but the initial community posts were back when it was called New User interface.

See overviews and impressions from:

- [CreateAndBreak](http://www.createandbreak.net/2012/02/more-siteedit-insight.html) (my post)
- [BuildingBlocks](http://blog.building-blocks.com/sdl-tridion-user-interface-2012-overview?utm_source=rss&utm_medium=rss&utm_campaign=sdl-tridion-user-interface-2012-ov)
- [CodedWeapon](http://codedweapon.com/2012/03/back-from-bootcamp/)
- [TridionDeveloper](http://www.tridiondeveloper.com/siteedit-2012-overview)
- [Nuno Linhares](http://nunolinhares.blogspot.com/2012/02/sweetedit.html)
- [Netwhisperer](http://www.netwhisperer.com/2012/10/31/sdl-tridion-new-user-interface-2012-overview/)

In terms of project scope, **be sure to include time to work with the client to create and help setup their prototype content, content types, and page types**. These features were already a part of SiteEdit 2009, but are now easier to configure.

Page and content types allow authors the ability to create new pages and content; they're based on business needs but need IT or development to set them up.

Answer (score 3):

Though a lot of references are already mentioned in above answers. 
Here I would like to suggest you one point regarding the estimate.

There are two possibilities in your case first is upgrade and other is migrate. Effort will vary in both the cases.

Though you have already mentioned migrate in your question but I am not sure that you are differentiating it with upgrade.
If you go with the upgrade, your existing SiteEdit-enabled VBScript/JScript templating code only requires you to add a Javascript command and republish. Do bear in mind, however, that your templating code is deprecated.

Otherwise, if you will go with second option, migration would be part of a larger effort to migrate your VBScript templates to modular templating.